# Foreach a set of where conditions with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to do something like this, and getting compiler errors:

```
var query = from ev in dataConnection.event_info
                       where ev.isdeleted == 0
                       select ev;
foreach (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression whereCond in whereConditionsList)
{
    query.Where(whereCond);
}
```

Error:

**`'System.Linq.IQueryable<JsonApplicationServices.event_info>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\jzumbrum\perforce_jzumbrum_laptop\jzumbrum_laptop\SlamRun\WCFService\Events.cs 31  21  WCFService`**

How can I create a collection of `where` conditions, and then `foreach` over them?

Comment: what does the definition of the variable "query" look like?

Comment: Updated question so I could get the nice formatting.

Comment: Apparently you have `Func<TSource,int,bool>` instances in `whereConditionsList`, whereas is should be `Func<TSource,bool>`.

Comment: can you also provide code describing how whereConditionsList is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't figure out how to foreach over a where Condition, but I did figure out how to append to my where condition, and my question in a different way here:
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875547/combine-predicates-in-linq-to-entities)

The gist of is that you need to add query.AsExpandable.Where()

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
// query defined earlier...

foreach (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression whereCond in whereConditionsList)
{
    query = query.Where(whereCond);
}
```

But the `Expression` thing seems funny...

Comment: Yea, I needed to do query = ..., but the expression is still not right.