# Combine Predicates in Linq-to-entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to dynamically build my list of where conditions.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
protected Expression<Func<event_info, bool>> _wherePredicate = c => true;

public void main() 
{

 _wherePredicate = _wherePredicate.And(c => c.createdby == 6);
 _wherePredicate = _wherePredicate.And(c => c.isdeleted == 0);

 var query = from ev in dataConnection.event_info
                       where ev.isdeleted == 0
                       select ev;
 Results = query.Where(_wherePredicate).ToList(); 
}
```

Except this doesn't work because linq-to-entities doesn't support the Invoke method.

What's a good way I can combine predicates in linq-to-entities?

Comment: [LINQ to Entities: Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, you need to add this:

Results = query.**AsExpandable**.Where(_wherePredicate).ToList();

And then it just magically works!

I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx